# ConfigParser options with % in value

Tags: python, configparser

I'm trying to parse a .conf file with ConfigParser, and some of the values have a '%' in the value.

Example of the config below:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
```

When I parse this using RawConfigParser, it sets `server string` to

```
%h server (Samba, Ubuntu)\n\n\n\ndns proxy = no\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n...REST_OF_CONFIG_SECTION
```

Where the bunch of `\n` are blank lines between config options.  And when I use the normal `ConfigParser`, I get an `InterpolationSyntaxError` with the error

> '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%h server (Samba, Ubuntu)\n\n\n\ndns proxy = no\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n

Editing the string before passing it to ConfigParser (replacing % with %%) parses it, but does the same issue as RawConfigParser where it parses the rest of the options as a single line.

How am I supposed to properly parse values that have a % in them?

Comment: The error message literally says hot to fix it: `'%' must be followed by '%'`

Comment: @DYZ but what if that is not an option since the config file would no longer be valid for the program? (samba)

Answer (score 3):

Disable interpolation in the normal ConfigParser:

```
configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
```

Comment: Can you please explain interpolation and what will be the consequences of making `interpolation=None`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Documentation. you have to escape the % by using %%

https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

```
[Escape]
gain: 80%%  # use a %% to escape the % sign (% is the only character that needs to be escaped)
```

in your case:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %%h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
```

Comment: But what if that would make the .conf file invalid for the application it's being used for?

Comment: why it is going to invalid if you change the percentage?

Comment: It's reading specifically `smb.conf`, the configuration file for samba.  Samba uses  replacements with a single percent, such as %h for hostname.  Doing %%h would invalidate the configuration.